# How to hide URL Bar on IOS Safari on iPhone X and newer?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, meta-tags, landscape

I would like Safari on Mobile to hide the URL Bar when the iPhone is in Landscape mode.

I used the following code which works perfectly on my iPhone 7, but on the newest iPhones is not (Tested on iPhone 11 and 11 Max). The URL bar is hidden when i flip the phone from Portrait to Landscape but then appears again when I touch the navigation bar (position: fixed;) which goes underneath the url bar.

```
<!-- Meta Tag -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui, window.scrollTo(0,1)">
<!-- Fullscreen Mode -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<!-- Status Bar -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```